# Create 2D array using new Array().fill(0) bug?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create a 2d array, but i found an interesting behavior

```
const column = 10;
const row = 10;

let matrix = new Array(row).fill(new Array(column).fill(0));

matrix[0][1] = 1;

console.log(matrix)
```

and to my surprise i get the result as below:

```
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

the entire column number 1 is set to 1, may I know why am I getting this behavior?

Comment: all array elements are referring to a single array

Comment: @PranavCBalan do u mind explain more?

Comment: `new Array(column).fill(0)` creates an array with length `column` and elements as `0`.  `new Array(row).fill(....)` which fills with the array you were created, which is not creating different array for each... instead the reference to the array act as element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)** method filling with the same array that the elements are the reference to a single array. So you need to create separate arrays as elements. So updating one will reflect all other since they are not different array they are the same.

Using **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** you can create and generate values by [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Parameters).

```js
const column = 10;
const row = 10;

let matrix = Array.from({
  // create array of length `row`
  length: row 
  // map function to generate values
}, () => new Array(column).fill(0));

matrix[0][1] = 1;

console.log(matrix)
```

Comment: sry, still dont get it..why is it reference to a single array? since it generates `row` times of that new array?

Comment: @Tim :  first it creates an array of length `row` afterward it filling with a single array..... the fill act like `matrix[0] = matrix[1] = .. = matrix[row - 1] = new Array(column).fill(0);` so all the array elemnts are refering to same array....

Comment: @Tim :  The array would be like `ref=[.....];[ref,ref,ref,...,ref]` ....

Answer (score 1):

@PranavCBalan have right.

It's something like that:

```
let matrix = new Array(row);
var x = new Array(column).fill(0);
matrix[0] = matrix[1] = .. = matrix[column - 1] = x;
```

Your matrix is array of the one object.